# iOS how to replace my app icon in .app file and resign?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now, I have a project that has to distribute in 20 or more 'ipa' files according In-house distribution. However, these files are totally identical. They are divided into different 'ipa' files by different icons and different names. 
It is my question that I rename the icon file into same name with my icon file in Xcode project. And build it to be a .app file, resign it after I replaced different icons in this .app file. But it doesn't works. So what should I do? 
I don't want to archive it over 20 times to get the ipa files!!That's painful and boring.

detail: 
First, I use a command `xcodebuild` to get a .app file.
`xcodebuild -workspace ${projectDir}/xxxxx.xcworkspace -scheme ${schemeName} -configuration Release clean -sdk iphoneos build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}" SYMROOT="${projectDir}/build"`
Before I do this, I've set [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGq3I.png) in Xcode. 
Then, I open the app file and I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9QK5.png).
So I decide to change the icon so that I don't have to re-archive many times. So I replace this by else [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNv34.png). They have same names.
After that, I resign this .app file according using this command
`xattr -cr $ipaPath/Payload/myproject.app
codesign -f -s "xxxxxx" --entitlements $Entitlements $ipaPath/Payload/myproject.app`. And I upload to a platform and download from there. The icon was not changed(is the first [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9QK5.png) not [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNv34.png)). So why did it happen? and how could I solve it.
By the way, I also re-write the plist file to change the `DisplayName`, it works.

Comment: isn't that a problem solved by Targets ? https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/

Comment: You can build and sign apps on the command line using `xcodebuild`. What have you tried?  You could also look at using fastlane

Comment: I didn't test it. But you can try https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2 . You can detect your app's bundle id for auto call the `changeIcon` function

Comment: Use Fastlane for resigning your app. very easy with Fastlane.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the command you are using and describe your problem more clearly than "it does not work"

Comment: And I confirm that the icons have the identical name with the name which are in the general setting. Should I set something in the plist? Or is there any else method to solve my problem? Thank you. @Paulw11

Comment: You should edit your question to include that detail

Comment: ok, I'm sorry wait a minute. @Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to re-build the app to get the icons into the bundle; re-signing is not sufficient.

I would suggest the following:

1. In the asset catalog, you create App Icon assets for each target and give them an individual name, e.g. `AppIconTaget1` and so on
2. In the *build settings* of each target, you create a variable named e.g. `TargetAppIconName` and assign it accordingly to `AppIconTarget1` and so on (so in the second target, `TargetAppIconName == AppIconTarget2`)
3. In the *Info.plist* file, you assign the `CFBundleIconName` entry to the *value* of this variable, e.g. `$(TargetAppIconName)`

Then, without any pre/post copying and so on, you should get individual icons after building each and every target.

Answer (score -1):

its seems must archive 20 times
in your project => General => TARGETS, you can create 20 targets with ,
set target different icons and different names.
then archive them with auto script(use xcodebuild)